# A weakly bounded operator family on a Banach space is also uniformly bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given $X$ a Banach space, to say $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, a family of bounded linear operators from $X$ to another normed space $Y$, is *weakly bounded* is to say that, fixing any $x\in X$ and $y^*\in Y^*$, the numerical set $\{y^*(A_i x)\}_{i\in I}$ is bounded. Now the result to prove is: a weakly bounded family must also be uniformly bounded, i.e., $\{\|A_i\|\}$ is bounded.

This is apparently a corollary of Banach-Steinhaus Theorem (aka uniform boundedness principle, UBP). I think proof by contradiction is the right track, but I've been stuck on the proper choice of $y^*$. My hunch is that we need to vary $y^*$ rather than just comstructing a specific one to violate the weak boundedness.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: First show that if $y^\ast (A) $ is a bounded set for ever $y^\ast$, then $A \subset Y $ is bounded.

Comment: @PhoemueX that's exactly the difficult part.

Comment: @PhoemueX it still boils down to finding *one* $y^*$ such that $y^*(A)$ is unbounded when $A$ is unbounded.

Comment: Use the embedding of $Y $ into its bidual and the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks! This is in effect an answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I hinted at in the comments, one way to show this is as follows:

1. One uses the **isometric** embedding of $Y$ into its bidual to show that if $A \subset Y$ is such that $y^\ast (A) \subset \Bbb{K}$ is bounded for each $y^\ast \in Y^\ast$, then $A$ is a bounded set. **Note**: This does not even use completeness of $Y$, just that of $Y^\ast$.
2. Using the predecing point and the given assumptions, we conclude that for every $x \in X$, the set $\{A_i x \,:\, i \in I\}$ is bounded in $Y$. Now, another application of the uniform boundedness principle yelds the claim. This uses completeness of $X$.